# Voice control without cloud service

Tags: android, offline, voice-command

I'm searching for an Android app to voice control my phone.

Requirements:

- Saying "Call Peter" in my headset shall dial this contact
- **No cloud based service!** Due to privacy concerns. I don't want to upload my contact list to Google, etc. This rules out most services like "Hello Google", "utter!", "S-voice", "Vlingo" (especially if you google the last service you might understand why I am reluctant to use cloud services)
- Good understanding of English and/or German

No must:

- Control additional apps, like writing SMS, taking notes, playing music

Comment: No Finnish? ;) Sorry, don't want to disappoint you, but there's not much. Especially if you want it open-source to be sure. AFAIK [*Dragon*](http://www.dragonmobileapps.com/android/) could match, but I'm not sure if their *Android* app works offline. *Utter* is known to have offline-capabilities, but I doubt that's its default…

Comment: Finnish :-) :-) :-)  I checked "Utter!" Thei claim that no data is uploaded. However at start of the application theiy ask me to select a Voice engine. The only option is "Google text to speech". I know that I can download voice files for that locally, however I don't trust Google :-/

Comment: Neither do I, which is why I don't use it. I've also looked for a replacement and found none. And I know the *Gadgetbridge* team wants an open-source, trustable and reliable voice engine (library or app to interface) as well and has found none so far. As for "Finnish" (the *language* that is): Thought you came from Mike's MUC (if that doesn't ring a bell for you, you didn't), as the very same question came up there and one of the answers was to check here :) You can check with [my voice assistant list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_personalassistants) if you wish.

Comment: It did ring a bell :-) Nice list. Seems that you have spend already some time on this topic.

Comment: I regularly do on those lists (currently just going over them all for a refresh, adding hints on "intrusive libraries" like *Flurry* and the likes). Same for my own F-Droid repo I mentioned on the MUC yesterday. But let's not chat here in the comments; see me in our chat room if you wish :) // Good luck here – and if you found something, please ring my bell to let me participate :)

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla is now generating an open source voice recognicion. See: https://voice.mozilla.org/
Althrough no demo is available now, this might be a good altenative in the furture.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software#Open_source_acoustic_models_and_speech_corpus_(compilation))?

As you can see, there a barely any frameworks that do speech to text, let alone automation like you want.

Your best bet is [mycroft](https://community.mycroft.ai/t/easiest-way-to-use-mycroft-completely-offline/3741) which is focused on running on it's own device.

Either way a lot of coding from your side would be required.